# Do Object Oriented Cobol need Java or some other language to execute?

Tags: oop, cobol

I've seen people mention java and .net when talking about Cobol and haven't seen a true & complete piece of OOP Cobol codes. It it true?
If not, where and how can I create an instance in Cobol main (don't know so I said so) like in other language ( what I could do with them in cobol)?
I mean, what I read is how to create classes. I didn't see they actually give out any example to do with those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not going to find a "true and complete" example of a full OO COBOL application in the world of IBM Enterprise COBOL (other vendors may have been more successful). OO extentions for IBM Enterprise COBOL are only there to allow interoperability with Java applications, not to develop complete OO based COBOL systems.

See the response by tmross to [this post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=340369&tstart=120) on IBM's COBOL Cafe web site concerning a pure OO COBOL HelloWorld program. It pretty much outlines what the real problem is. Note, Tom Ross (tmross) is a major player in IBM's COBOL compiler development so he speaks with some authority.

BTW... I am in no way affiliated with IBM.

Answer (score 3):

COBOL is a language, whereas Java and .NET are both a language (or a family of languages) and a virtual machine operating on their own instruction set such as byte code or msil (this is not technically correct, as the languages and vm's are actually separate, but the statement holds for imprecise colloquial usage).

The use of any of the object oriented features of COBOL requires a compiler that understands and supports those features. Running in a virtual framework (JRE, .NET) requires a compiler that can compile down to byte code or msil.